# Does Rails only make one precompiled file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

Does Rails 4 precompile just one file based on `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile` and use it for all pages?

Comment: There's one CSS, one JavaScript, plus a number of image assets normally, but you can configure this.

Comment: Thanks! So one for the whole app or one for each page? Is jquery_include_tag only used for development mode then?

Comment: For the whole app, generally, it packages up `assts/` accordingly. You'll see N files included in development mode, but in production that packs down to one that includes them all.

Comment: So why use jquery_include_tags or similar in header files to include based on manifest files if it goes in one big file anyways? Just for development then?

Comment: Use what you get in the default layout and extend from there using the asset system. Try a production deploy and you'll see how it works. I think `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` might do it as well to give you a taste.

Comment: Its for the whole app but you can add a few classes to the layout such as  `<body class="<%= controller_name %> <%= controller_action %>">` and use that to hook specific CSS or JS onto.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I'm just a little confused why we have jquery_include_tags if we are just including everything based on whatever is in the assets precompile config. Is it just for files that aren't part of the pipeline?

Comment: Ohhh I think I understand now. So jquery_include_tags will automatically include the precompiled version then if its part of the asset pipeline. If not then it will include the regular version?